# jwplayer set fullscreen mode onclick

Tags: jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Why this code in not working for me ?
I want set player in fullscreen mode on click...

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
    file: 'file.mp4',
    image: 'poster.jpg',
    width: '600px',
    aspectratio: '4:3'
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#player').click(function() {
        jwplayer('player').setFullscreen(true);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the JW Player API Reference:

> Note there is no API call to set fullscreen, due to phishing-related
>   security restrictions in both Flash and HTML5.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot set fullscreen via the API.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950191/jwplayer-full-screen-when-user-clicks-on-play ... will this work ?

Answer (score 0):

This will only work in HTML5 mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Full Screen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/C4lp6Dtd-el5vTWpr.mp4",
        image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg",
        primary: 'html5',
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
    jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function() { jwplayer().setFullscreen(true); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28950999/1877909

If you are using `angular`,  you can use [angularFullScreen](https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen) which only works for html5