# JWplayer Full screen when user clicks on play

Tags: jquery, html, jwplayer

How do I make JWplayer full screen as soon as a user clicks on the play button? I couldn't find anything relating to this on their support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only work in HTML5 mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Full Screen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/C4lp6Dtd-el5vTWpr.mp4",
        image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg",
        primary: 'html5',
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
    jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function() { jwplayer().setFullscreen(true); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I can see now how it perfectly works.

Comment: It will not. setFullscreen only works in html5, not Flash, and IE8 does not support HTML5.

Comment: @emaxsaun in this way can I disable fullscreen all the time or on display double tap.

Comment: suppose i have multiple videos then how to open particular video on  full screen ?

Comment: Email support <at> jwplayer <dot> com about that.

Comment: Use `jwplayer("player").on('displayClick', function() { jwplayer("player").setFullscreen(true); });` for v8 of jwplayer