# Jwplayer fullscreen - on clicking the custom button in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, jwplayer

I want to make jwplayer to fullscreen when I click on my own custom button `"Fullscreen"`.

I am aware of  [jwplayer().setFullscreen(true);](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28950999/1877909) but it is not supported in IE8.

I have also tried [AngularFullScreen](https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen) but it will also not support in IE8.

Is there any way to do this in IE8?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support it natively. SO knows about dirty hacks to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464332/internet-explorer-full-screen-mode

Comment: @unconnected : Thanks for answering. dirty hacks will also work, please add those as answer :P

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't support software switch to fullscreen. You have to emulate F11 key press. Check this topic: [Internet Explorer full screen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464332/internet-explorer-full-screen-mode)

Comment: @hitesh Sorry, I don't know any more. I have luck to leave all deprecated stuff unsupported :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Because of a security limitation it is not possible to set fullscreen from outside of the flash player, not in Jwplayer, not in flowplayer. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

press f11 programatically by calling this function

```
function max() {
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
}
```